# Break Diet/Quarantine

Tags: word-usage

For the verb "*break*", many dictionaries have example usage sentences like:

> 1. He broke the law.
> 2. He broke the agreement.

Could the usage of "*break*" be expanded to "*diet*" and "*quarantine*" (MERS related):

> 3. He broke his ***diet***.
> 4. He broke the ***quarantine***.

Are 3 & 4 standard English?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I don't see anything wrong with either of those sentences.

In number 3, broke is being used in terms of "he broke [the rules *or* the pattern of] his diet." In number 4, broke is being used in terms of "he broke the [conditions of the] quarantine." [This Newsweek article](http://www.newsweek.com/nbcs-nancy-snyderman-breaks-ebola-quarantine-apologizes-277380) uses the 4th sentence.

From Newsweek:

> "NBC’s Nancy Snyderman Breaks Ebola Quarantine, Apologizes"

Comment: Agreed. But in AmE we usually say someone "went off" their diet, which is a bit milder, allowing for the possibility they might resume after a short lapse, in which case the diet would not be considered "broken".